# What is the format for crc32c hash in Firebase storage rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to use the `request.resource.crc32c` from Firebase Storage rules (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/#properties_2)

My goal is to have a rule like:

```
match /blobs/{hash}/{fileName} {
   allow read;
   allow write: if request.resource.crc32c == hash;
}
```

But I'm getting permissions denied for every write I'm trying. The Firebase documentation doesn't give any information about the format of the CRC32C hash: Is it hex, int, uint, base64 or something else ?

Comment: My guess is this one: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hashes-etags#_CRC32C

Answer (score 0):

It's the big-endian representation of the crc32c value encoded as a base64 string (NOT base64url)